# Create a retail store map by plotting xy coordinates using some web based code (javascript, jquery, html, etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maps

I would like to create a retail store map using some web based code or library (javascript, jQuery, html, etc) but not sure where to start and want some direction/example of what I could use.

Precisely, I want a way to plot a list of objects with x,y coordinates on a webpage then assign an image for the object.

The data looks like this:

```
Object_ID,x-coor,y-coor,Object_Type
A1,45.78,23.50,Table
A2,35.98,34.45,Bookcase
A3,45.45,19.55,Chair
A4,78.66,73.15,Counter
```

I want something really basic like the attached picture.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this library http://draggabilly.desandro.com/

html:

```
<h1>Draggabilly - with jQuery</h1>
<div class="draggable"></d
```

script:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var $draggable = $('.draggable').draggabilly();
});
```

try it on 
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/yyRapr